# How can i disable the automatic build triggered from build configuration in openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I am trying to create a cicd pipeline with openshift. Initially, when creating the application using 'oc new-app' command, it automatically triggers the build. How i need to disable the initial build other than deleting or cancel the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i need to disable the initial build other than deleting or cancel the build?

`oc new-app` can not prevent the initial build.
It had discussed here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/15429
Unfortunately it does not implement now.

But, you can prevent initial build as removing all triggers from `buildConfig` by modifying yaml of `buildConfig` manually.

- First export `oc new-app` as yaml format.

```
# oc new-app --name=test \
  centos/ruby-25-centos7~https://github.com/sclorg/ruby-ex.git -o yaml --dry-run > test.yml
```

- Remove all triggers as changing the configuration to `triggers: []`.

```
strategy:
  sourceStrategy:
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: ruby-25-centos7:latest
  type: Source
triggers: []
```

After modifying, create resources using `oc create -f`.

```
# oc create -f test.yml
imagestream.image.openshift.io/ruby-25-centos7 created
imagestream.image.openshift.io/ruby-ex created
buildconfig.build.openshift.io/ruby-ex created
deploymentconfig.apps.openshift.io/ruby-ex created
service/ruby-ex created
```

The build does not run until you run `oc start-build <bc name>` and `oc rollout latest dc/<dc name>`.

I hope this use case is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is helpfull. Is there any other way to do this automatically through command other than editing the build configuration manually?

Comment: @Pragathibaskar Unfortunately AFAIK, no, it isn't. There is no way unless modifying directly original template yaml.

Comment: I did like this, export COUNT=`oc get build|grep build-name|wc -l`  ;  oc apply -f ocp/buildconfig.yaml --wait=true;  if [[ "$COUNT" != "0" ]]; then oc start-build build-name --wait=true fi